# How to encode bytes as a printable unicode string (like base64 for ascii)

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am looking for an encoding of arbitrary byte data into an unicode string, that only contains printable characters, much like base64 for ascii.

I would be happy to find such an encoding for any unicode version.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "an utf8 string"? Any reason you don't just want to use base64?

Comment: @JonSkeet I have to send bytes over a channel that only accepts printable utf8 characters. Base64 would work of course, but i thought i could use much less characters by utilizing all the other printable characters utf8 offers beside the ascii chars.

Comment: You could use fewer characters, yes - but you'll find less support for it on other platforms (we have no idea which platforms you're using) and you may well find that later you need to convert it to an ASCII format anyway, for easier transport. If you can guarantee that this is the only place you need the encoded form, and you know exactly which versions of Unicode both ends use, it might be reasonable...

Comment: Note that you're really just talking about Unicode strings though - UTF-8 is a way of encoding Unicode, basically.

Comment: Now that i think of it such an encoding would need to consider the Unicode Version, but even an encoding for Unicode 1.0.0 should be much more efficient than base64? Is there such an encoding out there?

Comment: Yes, potentially. I suspect you could easily work out, say, 4096 printable characters, giving you 12 bits per character, encoding 3 bytes per 2 characters. I don't know of a *standardized* encoding like that, but it would basically be applying the same ideas as base64, but base4096...

Comment: You *do* need to express those characters as bytes at some point... you may be able to squeeze 3 bytes into 2 characters, but if both characters take two bytes each to encode in a Unicode encoding, then you're using 4 bytes for 3... It's questionable whether this is significantly more efficient than base64.

Comment: @deceze In my case only the number of characters is relevant, but yes that does not sound like a huge gain byte wise.

Comment: Can you show some example code of how you send a string to this channel, so we can get an idea of what you're trying to do? If you want to map "byte 0-255" to "256 printable Unicode characters", you'll have to make a mapping of byte-to-character and implement that mapping at both ends of the channel. Using a channel that accepts Unicode characters to transfer bytes is really the wrong way around though.

Comment: Why is the number of characters more relevant than the number of bytes? Are you encoding binary data to be posted to Twitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [UniBinary library](https://github.com/nst/UniBinary) seems to do what i am looking for:

> UniBinary is an encoding algorithm which packs arbitrary data into
>   printable Unicode characters.
>
> It can be used to send data through media such as Twitter which don't
>   allow binary data but allow Unicode characters.